# Will (3R,4S,5R)-1,3,4,5,6-pentahydroxyhexan-2-one tautomerise in nitric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, carbohydrates, tautomer

The following question was sent to me .The question is " Which of the following is  A ?"

**The given answer was a,b,c**

[image]

**Background**

If both ends of an aldose chain are oxidized to carboxylic acids the product is called an aldaric acid.
[image]

source : https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/VirtTxtJml/carbhyd.htm#carb2

**My thoughts**

[image]

- Options a and c are direct reactions.
- Option **b** gives **2** and  it can only rotated in the plane it is drawn (2D) by 180 degrees (http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/Carey5th/Ch07/ch7-7.html) to give **1**.
- How ever option d in acidic medium could tautomerise to give 3d , that on oxidation again gives 1.

Therefore answer should be **a,b,c,d**.

My answer hinges on tautomerisation of ketone is acidic medium. Would this compound (3R,4S,5R)-1,3,4,5,6-pentahydroxyhexan-2-one tautomerise in nitric acid ?

Any help in this regard is very much appreciated. Thankyou.

**reference :**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWNUJ.png) http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/Carey5th/Ch07/ch7-7.html

Comment: This link would suggest that direct oxidation of fructose leads to a trihydroxyglutaric acid. Thus, option d) appears to be eliminated. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/121328/oxidation-of-fructose-with-conc-hno3

Comment: I realize now that configuration at 3rd carbon will not change. While tautomerism can occur between 1st a d 2nd carbon. Good work guys, thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sir Arthur7 did a fine job of discrediting D-ketose (d) as a viable candidate for structure **A**. Belatedly, I will expand upon my comment above at the request of @Jan. [*In my comment above, "glutaric" should read "glucaric"*.] 
Assuming that $\ce{HNO3}$ is capable of tautomerizing the D-ketose via the enediol and accomplishing terminal oxidation, two epimeric aldaric acids could arise: D-gularic acid and D-idaric acid. Note that they only differ in the hydroxyl configuration at C<sub>2</sub>. Rotation of D-gularic by 180<sup>o</sup> about an axis perpendicular to the page results in a structure that is also recognized as L-glucaric acid. Thus, D-gularic and L-glucaric acid are identical. When the same rotation is performed on D-idaric acid, D-idaric acid is returned. Choices (a), (b) and (c) all produce D-glucaric acid (red box) while option (d) produces the enantiomer, L-glucaric acid, and the irrelevant D-idaric acid. Option (d) is not a viable structure for **A**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well I am just a high school student, so I may be wrong, and I beg pardon in advance, but I would like to share my notions about this topic.

@ChakravarthyKalyan I would like to ask you to review your last step in the conversion of 3d to 1. 3d on oxidation should yield this product (in the image)--which is by my knowledge not same as 1.

[image: Oxidation of 3d]

So even your theory does not yield (d) as the correct option, I assume. Also I doubt the double tautomerism of the compound in option (d) in acidic medium, though your mechanisms were convincing. This closely resembles Lobry-Debryn-van-Eckenstein rearrangement that occurs only in presence of alkaline medium.

As per my knowledge, ketoses in presence of strong oxidizing agents like conc. HNO3, undergo oxidative cleavage forming 2 carboxylic acids(acc. to Popoff's rule), or as @user55119 had pointed out to me, that alpha ketoacids can undergo oxidative decarboxylation and form CO2 and an acid(though its mechanism is quite unclear to me as well).

Comment: Oxidative decarboxylation is one consequence of nitric acid oxidation. If tautomerization occurs, D-idose (3c) and D-gulose (3d) would be formed. HNO3 oxidation of D-gulose would afford L-glutaric acid (aka, D-gularic acid) as 1, not D-glutaric acid as shown. Your structure as drawn id D-gularic acid. Rotated by 180o, It is L-glutaric acid.

Comment: This is essentially correct. The product 3d and 1 are enantiomers. This answer could expand on the fact more.